# While installing ruby "you requested building with '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path" in mac OS X

Tags: macos

I am new to mac OS X. I am trying to install ruby, but I am getting error like this:

```
you requested building with '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to install third party software on the Mac is to use [Macports](http://macports.org).

- Install Xcode, including the Command Line Tools.
- Download and install macports.
- Update macports:

  ```
  $ sudo port selfupdate
  ```
- Install ruby:

  ```
  $ sudo port install ruby
  ```

and it will install itself into `/opt/local/...`.

The port itself looks like it will compile with later versions of `clang`, although I haven't personally verified that.